# Obtain User's phone number from Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, security, webkit

Real story:

User taps on an advertisement inadvertently in Mobile Safari (iOS 5.0.1) and closes the ad immediately. Few minutes later Receives an SMS saying she successfully subscribed to an erotic video service.

Is it possible to obtain user's phone number using JS? Is this a known security hole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no API for this information, but the network operator may provide it to websites (either intentionally, or perhaps [unintentionally](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/mobiles/o2-apparently-shares-your-phone-number-with-sites-you-visit-50006760/)).